# How to create BST for arithmetic expression

Tags: c++

I am a c++ leaner, I am trying to create a BST tree for this expression: 2346*+/8+, and do inorder and postorder to get the in-fix version, and postfix version of the expression. I am having difficulty to create the binary tree for the expression. Here is my peso code:

```
Tree:
Stack:
inorder fn{}
postorder fn{}
main{
  input the file;
    while(expression){
      if(digit){
         s.push}
      else if(operator){
         s.top = right;
         s.pop;
         s.top = left;
         s.pop;
         T1 = new Tree(operator, left, right);
     }
    }
```

the tree I want to create is like this

```
           +
          / \
        (/)  8
        / \
       +   2  
      / \
     *   3
    / \
   4   6
```

my problem for this code is that after create (4*6) tree, I cant link (+3) with (4*6). Please help me.

Thanks to Drew McGowen, I have updated my code, now I am push the 4*6 tree back to the stack, here is the code:

```
while(input_file >> expression){
    if(isdigit(expression[0])){
        sscanf(expression,"%c",&digit);
        printf("reading a number: %c \n",digit);
        Tree* s.push(digit);
    }
    else {
        sscanf(expression,"%c",&oper);
        printf("reading an operator: %c \n",oper);
        T1 = new Tree(s.top(), NULL, NULL);
        s.pop();
        T2 = new Tree(s.top(), NULL, NULL);
        s.pop;
        myTree = new Tree(oper, T1, T2);
        s.push(myTree);
```

I am keep getting error message, can some1 check the code for me please. thanks guys.

Hi guys, I think the main part is on the right track, but how should I modify the stack function to accept the tree ? here is my stack functions:

```
void Stack::Push(char newthing) {
index++;
data[index] = newthing;
}
  void Stack::Pop() {
  if (index > -1) { index--; }
 }
 char Stack::Top() {
 return data[index];
```

Comment: Eh? You already have the postfix version of the expression. You can evaluate that directly. No need to build a tree or derive infix for it at all.

Comment: Once you create the `4*6` tree, just push it back onto the stack.

Comment: yea, but if I push 4*6 tree (newTree) back to the stack, while the loop running one more time, then the newTree will become right child of the new tree. I need to figure a way out to use the while loop to create the whole tree. Thanks, I think your idea is pointing the right way

Comment: I need to create the tree to do inOrder and postOrder traversal, and output the result as the infix version with all parenthesis, so I need to create the tree, print out the inOrder result as the infix, and postOrder as the postfix.

Comment: Your don't need to create the tree for post-order traversal. The result of a post-order traversal is identical to the postfix input.

Comment: k, thanks. but my problem is not with the postRoder, I have to complete the tree to do the inOrder traversal :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your stack contains numbers. In order to parse an expression in post-fix notation to a stack, the stack should contain tree-elements.

*Pseudo-code*:

```
main{
  input the file;
    while(expression){
      if(digit){
         s.push(new Tree(digit)); //create leaf-element
      }
      else if(operator){
         Tree tr = s.pop();
         Tree tl = s.pop();
         T1 = new Tree(operator,tl,tr);
     }
}
```

This is also more or less the way a L(AL)R-parser works.

**About your code:**

- you should reverse the order to `T2` and `T1`, because you are popping from the stack;
- `T1` and `T2` should be simple pop operations, no constructor calls; and
- you should construct a tree node (leaf) in the digit case.

  ```
  while(input_file >> expression){
      if(isdigit(expression[0])){
          sscanf(expression,"%c",&digit);
          printf("reading a number: %c \n",digit);
          s.push(new Tree(digit,NULL,NULL)); //create new leaf
      }
      else {
          sscanf(expression,"%c",&oper);
          printf("reading an operator: %c \n",oper);
          T2 = s.top(); //T2 instead of T1 and simple pop
          s.pop();
          T1 = s.top(); //T1 instead of T2 and simple pop
          s.pop;
          myTree = new Tree(oper, T1, T2);
          s.push(myTree);
      }
  }
  ```

If the input stream is a valid one (for instance not `1+` or `12+6`), the result is a stack with one element: the root of the expression tree.